# Bitwise & operation in javascript

Tags: javascript, bitwise-and

I try to understand the following behavior in java script (node):

> const num = 0xffffffff

> num
> // 4294967295

> num & num
> // -1

why num & num is calculated as signed integer and when the variable is define at first time (num = 0xffffffff) its calculated as unsigned

Comment: bitwise operators are 32bit signed in javascript

Comment: "*when the variable is define at first time (num = 0xffffffff) its calculated as unsigned*" - it isn't. It's a **double** in fact, like every number in javascript. Only when `&` operates on it, it gets converted to an 32 bit integer where signed/unsigned plays a role.

Comment: In JavaScript, numbers are implemented in double-precision 64-bit binary format IEEE 754. Integer values up to ±2^53 − 1 can be represented exactly. Some operations (like bitwiseNOT, leftShift , signedRightShift, bitwiseOr, bitwiseAnd, bitwiseXOR) uses 32 bit signed inter, some (unsignedRightShift, Math.clz32, Math.imul, index of array) uses an unsigned 32 bit integer. But you also have BigInts: `const num = 0xffffffffn; (num & num) === num`